# How to add a new pc to a domain with name of old pc

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-7, domain, domain-controller

**Some Background...**
A local small non-profit has recently lost their network guy (died unexpectedly) and I've been asked to help then install windows on some new pc's and set up wifi and printers access... real basic stuff.

I work as a programmer, run my own home network consisting of windows and linux machines, Samba, web and database servers, Node, .NET, Pyton, etc.  I'm comfortable with computers and know enough "networking stuff" to get stuff done and to probably be dangerous... but I'm no admin.

**The Question...**

Assuming that the old pc will not remain on the network, can I not simply follow these instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/join-a-computer-to-a-domain) and add the new pc with the same name of the old pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the old PC is no longer connected to the network/domain. In fact, to be on the safer side, before doing anything on new PC, remove the old PC from domain. Also, change the hostname of old PC to avoid any accidental conflict in future. Else, in the future if you wish to use this older PC (and given that new PC was joined to domain with old PC's name), you may have trust relationship problem which is frustrating.

You've 2 options here to proceed:

1. You need to reset the account of the computer object in Active Directory before joining this new PC to domain. Then you can join this new PC to domain retaining the old system's name.
2. Dis-join the old PC from domain, change the hostname (to be on a safer side). Other option would be to delete the computer object from the AD console (dsa.msc / ADUC), and join this new PC with the same old PC's name.

I'd anytime prefer the 2nd option.

**NOTE:** By default, any user with administrative privilege (local OR domain level) can dis-join the PC from domain.